# Is ROWID a safe way to SELECT-UNLOAD-UPDATE rows in Teradata? Is it the quickest way?

Tags: sql, teradata, etl

is it possible to retrieve rows from Teradata and then refer back to them by ROWID? Is ROWID stable in the sense that SELECT followed by UPDATE on a ROWID will **always** result in the same row being affected? Or can it change between statements?

Secondly, is using ROWID the quickest way?

Background:

we want to combine all rows inside a table that are duplicates but have consequetive time intervals per group; leaving only one that has the earliest start and update it with the latest end date. We could probably write SQL that does this, but if performant, we prefer an ETL process for transparency (e.g. to see how many rows were deleted) and flexibility.

Comment: Don't think Teradata has a rowid function.  You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to accomplish the same thing.  As far as row_number, or any other windowing function, producing consistent results, that's up to you. For example, if you have multiple rows for the same partitions where the order by columns match, you'll get inconsistent results.

Comment: frankly I am now confused because I would say it does have a rowid?

Comment: There *is* a pseudocolumn `rowid` but it's usually disabled (has been abused too much). The `rowid` is the unique identifier of a row within a table, but as the RowHash is part of it it will change when the Primary Index (or partition) changes. And it's not the quickest way, it's *always* a Full Table Scan (on purpose). Normalizing consecutive (or overlapping) time ranges can be done in different ways, OLAP, td_normalize_meet, maybe `select normalize` or a *normalized table* what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have a temp table that I want to merge into an existing one. So it works, i will just match on all columns. That actually answers the question, if you upgrade your comment to a reply, I will accept it as the answer... thanks